# PowerShell Error loading format file DotNetTypes.format.ps1xml

Tags: powershell, nuget

I have just updated to nuget 1.6 and now I get this message in visual studio's Package Manager Console

```
There were errors in loading the format data file: Microsoft.PowerShell.Core,
Error in file C:\Windows\SysWOW64\WindowsPowerShell\v1.0\DotNetTypes.format.ps1xml: 
Data at the root level is invalid. Line 1, position 1
```

Any ideas how to I fix that?

I'm using 64 bit windows 7 if it matters.

Comment: It sounds like the XML file is invalid in some way. Could you post it's contents? Or at least the first few lines?

Comment: Good point, I didn't even try to look at the file. Turns out header of the file was completely corrupt (weird characters) so I got the file from another machine, now the problem is you can't modify or overwrite that file. I even tried [link](http://download.sysinternals.com/Files/PendMoves.zip) and still didn't succeed. Does anyone know any better way of overwriting an "in use by windows" file?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Resolved.

Downloaded Hirens Boot CD iso
Burned that to cd
Booted from cd
Selected Dos based programs\Mini Windows XP - was able to overwrite the corrupted file with genuine file I got from my buddy

Comment: Do you know you can "accept" your own answer  (click on the tick to the left of the answer) - and then people will know that your problem has been solved :)